# How does the distribution curve gets modified if I take some molecules out of the gaseous system following the Maxwell-Boltzmann law?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

If you have a gas of molecules following Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution then plot for the distribution curve is gaussian. Now, If I take out some molecules from it then how does the distribution curve gets modified?

Comment: How are you taking them out? Are you using effusion?

Answer (score 0):

If the Maxwellian is normalized to the number of molecules $N$, after extracting $n$ molecules and after equilibration, you'll get a Maxwellian normalized to $N-n$.

The Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution is a property of the system at thermodynamic equilibrium. Therefore, as soon as equilibrium has been achieved after perturbation, one ends up with the same distribution function.